# Write an egrep-style regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a problem with writing an egrep-style regex.

I have several words, like “tryout”, “pastry”, etc.

How do I write an egrep-style regular expression that matches “try”, but not inside these words?

I tried `\btry\b` regex, but it does not seem to work.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: use word boundary `\btry\b`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\b` for word boundaries. You can use a regex like this:

```
\btry\b
```

If you also want an ignorecase you could use the `i` flag. Or an inline flag like this:

```
(?i)\btry\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY7oD5/1)**

Answer (score 0):

In [`egrep` regex tutorial](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~tal/3261/fall07/handout/egrep_mini-tutorial.htm), you can find an example:

```
egrep <flags> '<regular expression>' <filename>
```

Then, to detect word boundaries,

> `egrep` symbol pair are the word boundaries `\<` and `\>` which respectively denote the beginning and ending of a word

So, use this regex, that will list all the lines in *searchfile.txt* containing the word `try` or `Try` (as `-i` option makes matching case-insensitive).

```
egrep -i '\<try\>' searchfile.txt
```